# Drawing elements on top of elements loaded by js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, z-index

Novice here!

I downloaded and used a template for my portfolio site. 
While trying to tweak it, I decided I wanted to draw one element overlapping the one immediately below it. I tried several things, such as changing the z-indices of the elements and their children like so

```
.bottom-element, .bottom-element * {
  z-index: 1;
}

.top-element, .top-element * {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I think the real problem has to do with the javascript files that were included with template. The top element that i want to do the overlapping is an svg path that acts as a fancy border for a content div, and the part i wanted to be overlapped is fancy gallery that is controlled by js[(image of the problem area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp6Zt.png). I am guessing that the scripts run and load the images after the initial html/css files are done? (Don't know much about it!)

Is there a way to make the svg draw over the gallery thumbnails? Or is it too complex and I shouldn't bother?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be easier to help you if we could see more of an example.  You probably want to position your images and use the `top` property to move them around.  You most likely want `absolute` or `relative`  Have a look at this: https://codemyviews.com/blog/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning.  If it doesn't its probably not worth bothering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed) so make sure you have that first.

Usually you add the relative as it won't actually change it's position unless you are giving it positional values.